# Braintree Drop-In UI CVV field disabled when type enter

Tags: braintree

When I enter in the CVV or Expired field and keypress enter, the field is immediately disabled and the data can not be re-entered.

Comment: Could you provide more information, such as your client-side code?

Comment: I'd like to know if the issue is resolved?

Comment: Issue resolved, is because I use the old drop-UI (2.x) https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/issues/205

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently and wasn't sure what was the cause of it. At the end I upgraded my Braintree version from 3.18 to 3.22 and it worked. Maybe you have the same issue, so give it a try :)